# Create datetime object from this string?

Tags: php, datetime

I've run into a small programming problem. I need to do some time calculations, but as an input I only have a string - so basically I'll need to convert this string to a date/time object in PHP. It's the conversion I'm having trouble with.

```
$endtimestamp = "September 1, 2012 13:00 PM";

$doesntwork = strtotime(trim($endtimestamp));
$doesntwork2 = date_create_from_format("l, F j, Y G:i A", $endtimestamp);
$doesntwork3 = date("l, F j, Y G:i A", strtotime($endtimestamp));
```

To be quite honest, I have no idea why these functions don't work as they are supposed to. SO far, other online resources have been vague at best. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that `13:00 PM` doesn't make any sense.  It's either `1:00 PM` *or* `13:00`.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this anomaly. Unfortunately, I have no control over the input provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems here.

One is that `13:00 PM` doesn't make any sense.  It's either `1:00 PM` *or* `13:00`.

```
strtotime("September 1, 2012 13:00");
```

Also your format `l, F j, Y G:i A` doesn't match your input string.

Either the format should be: `F j, Y G:i A`, or the string should be `Saturday, September 1, 2012 13:00 PM`.

Answer (score 3):

That happens because you have some strange `l,` in the beginning

If you use this format:

```
'F j, Y G:i A'
```

it works fine